# Excel - How do I return a color in a cell based on no value in a different cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a rule in Excel to change the color of one cell based on an empty value in a different cell on the same sheet.

The basic premise is having the color change based on the tardiness of an assignment. Some of the assignments haven't been started yet, so they shouldn't be the same color has ones that are late or on time. I know it would be easiest to just add some value like "NULL" to the empty cells, but everyone on the team is used to the cells being empty so I'd prefer to leave it that way.

Comment: have you tried using the conditional formatting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we wanted cell **B1** to turn yellow if cell **A1** is empty.  We can use conditional formatting.  Here is a short macro to set that up:

```
Sub Macro2()
    With Range("B1")
      .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISBLANK(A1)"
         .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
      With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
          .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .Color = 65535
          .TintAndShade = 0
      End With
      .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```